# Replication Mysql 5.5.33 to MariaDB 5.5.33 issue

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-replication

My configuration:
Master (Mysql 5.5.33)
Slave (MariaDb 5.5.33)

Slave status:

```
Variable    Value
Slave_IO_State  Waiting for master to send event
Master_Host     127.0.0.1
Master_User     sn1
Master_Port     12345
Connect_Retry   60
Master_Log_File     mysql-bin.000011
Read_Master_Log_Pos     1535
Relay_Log_File  mysqld-relay-bin.000014
Relay_Log_Pos   391
Relay_Master_Log_File   mysql-bin.000011
Slave_IO_Running    Yes
Slave_SQL_Running   Yes
Replicate_Do_DB     sn1db2
Replicate_Ignore_DB     
Replicate_Do_Table  
Replicate_Ignore_Table  
Replicate_Wild_Do_Table     
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table     
Last_Errno  0
Last_Error  
Skip_Counter    0
Exec_Master_Log_Pos     1535
Relay_Log_Space     2260
Until_Condition     None
Until_Log_File  
Until_Log_Pos   0
Master_SSL_Allowed  No
Master_SSL_CA_File  
Master_SSL_CA_Path  
Master_SSL_Cert     
Master_SSL_Cipher   
Master_SSL_Key  
Seconds_Behind_Master   0
```

After the inserting of a row in a table on master, the slave receive the change but don't apply it.

I disabled on slave the following features:

```
master_verify_checksum=OFF
slave_sql_verify_checksum=0
binlog_checksum=NONE
```

and I verified that are effectually disabled.

I verified the mariadb log:

Slave I/O: Notifying master by SET master_binlog_checksum= global.binlog_checksum failed with error: Unknown system variable binlog_checksum, Error_code: 1193

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this option on slave my.cnf file:
replicate-rewrite-db=sn1db->sn1db2